# Use optionnal/undefined array in generic with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

With Typescript and a much more complex project than the one presented, I want to create many collections based on the same model:

```
type BaseItem = {
  id: string;
};

type Item1Type = BaseItem & {
  name: string;
};

type Item2Type = BaseItem & {
  amount: number;
};

type CollectionType<I> = {
  'hydra:member': I[];
};

type StateType<I> = CollectionType<I>;

const test = <I extends StateType<I['hydra:member'][0]>>(data: I) => {
  return data;
};

const data1: StateType<Item1Type> = {'hydra:member': [{id: 'a', name: 'a'}]};
const data2: StateType<Item2Type> = {'hydra:member': [{id: 'a', amount: 1}]};

const result1 = test(data1);
const result2 = test(data2);
```

Here, everything works fine and `result1`/`result2` returns correctly typed data :

[image]

But with exactly the same code, if I try to make `StateType` can be `undefined` i have this error :

```
type StateType<I> = undefined | CollectionType<I>;

// TS error : The type '"hydra:member"' cannot be used to index type 'I'.ts(2536)
const test = <I extends StateType<I['hydra:member'][0]>>(data: I) => {
  return data;
};
```

I understand that since `StateType` is potentially `undefined`, it's no longer possible to rebuild it with the hydra:member key, but I'd like to make this optional (`StateType` = array correctly typed with `Item1Type`/`Item2Type` or `undefined`).

[image]

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mpK5bN) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you very much, it's perfect :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible fix would be to introduce another generic type constrained to `StateType` without `undefined` and using it we will take the type of array item of `hydra:member`, and the other to extend the previous one or `undefined`. We will use built-in [Exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) utility type to remove the `undefined` from the `StateType`:

```
type NonNullableStateType<I> = Exclude<StateType<I>, undefined>
```

Usage:

```
const test = <I extends NonNullableStateType<I['hydra:member'][0]>, K extends I | undefined>(data: K) => {
  return data;
};
```

Testing:

```
const result1 = test(data1); // CollectionType<Item1Type>
const result2 = test(data2); // CollectionType<Item2Type>
const result3 = test(undefined) // undefined
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgSWBAtlAvFA3gKCigEsATALigWACdiA7AcwG58BfV-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)